# I'm giving access to the children of parents of a newly created account, but i think its not working, or else how to check if this is working

Tags: apex, trigger

```
public class ManuallyShareAccount {
    public static void manualShare(List<Account> newList)
    {

        Set<Id> accSet= new Set<Id>();

        for(Account acc:[SELECT ParentId FROM Account WHERE Id IN:newList])
        {
            accSet.add(acc.ParentId);
        }
        List<Account> relatedAccount= new List<Account>([SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Account 
                                                           WHERE ParentId IN:accSet AND ID NOT IN :newList]);
       List<AccountShare> shareList= new List<AccountShare>();

       for(Account acc:newList)
        {
            for(Account acc1:relatedAccount)
            {
          AccountShare accshare= new AccountShare();
            accShare.AccountId=acc.id;
            accShare.UserOrGroupId=acc1.OwnerId;
                accShare.RowCause= Schema.AccountShare.RowCause.Manual;
                accShare.AccountAccessLevel='Read';
                accShare.OpportunityAccessLevel='Read';
                shareList.add(accShare);
        }
        }
        if(shareList.size()>0)
            insert shareList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code won't work if you insert children of two different parents in the same operation. It will share both accounts to the owners of all the other children of both parents, not the children of their own parents. You'd need to implement logic to handle this case.

One way to do so would be to create a `Map<Id, List<Account>>` from `relatedAccount`, where you map from the `Id` of a parent account to a list of that parent's children. Then, you can access that Map as you iterate over `newList` to ensure you add share records only for the owners of `acc`'s siblings.

To troubleshoot your sharing code, you can review the sharing rows created for any given Account simply by clicking the Sharing button in the user interface.

Additionally, you should write a full suite of unit tests for this functionality that includes both positive *and* negative cases bulk cases, and makes appropriate assertions to demonstrate that your code (a) does what it is supposed to do and (b) does not do what it is not supposed to do.

One easy way to implement negative cases is simply to assert the total count of records created. For example, suppose your unit test setup creates two parent accounts (A and B), each of which has two children owned by different users. Your unit test then inserts a new child of A. You know that you should expect to see exactly two `AccountShare` records created. You can run a `count()` query against `AccountShare` and assert that the result is equal to two, demonstrating that your code does not create any unexpected `AccountShare` records.